# Not able to delete image file using JAVA

Tags: java, delete-file

According to syntax it's correct but it's still not deleting image file.

```
try {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    File file1= new File("D:\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime()));
    if(file1.delete()){
        System.out.println(file1.getName()+"deleted");
    }
    else  {
        System.out.println(file1.getName()+"failed");
    }
}
catch(Exception po) {
    System.out.println(po);
}
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Where's the image file? You're looking for a file with the current timestamp as the name. Is someone constantly generating new files?

Comment: Are you sure `file1` is a valid file?

Comment: Consider using Java NIO, it has many enhancements over the older I/O classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: Its Printing else part.

Comment: yes file1 is correct file path.

Comment: Check your write permission for that file

Comment: @LEQADA This is Windows. There are no permissions.